# Need help modifying excerpt code

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress theme currently adds "..." to the end of the excerpt.  To read the whole post you either have to click on the featured image or on the post title.

I would like to replace the "..." with "...read more" and have it like to the post.

My blog is located @ www.cur-mudg-eon.com if you need to see how it's set up right now.

The code from the theme-function.php is located in full on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kVp6m5wn).

Here's the bit of code that I believe needs changing:

```
    <?php

// The excerpt based on words
function my_string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit)
  array_pop($words);
  return implode(' ', $words).'...';
}

// The excerpt based on character
function my_string_limit_char($excerpt, $substr=0)
{

$string = strip_tags(str_replace('...', '...', $excerpt));
if ($substr>0) {
    $string = substr($string, 0, $substr);
}
return $string;
    }
```

If more information/code is needed to answer my question let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [`codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Make_the_.22read_more.22_link_to_the_post) :

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">...Read More</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

Comment: Thanks Obmerk.  Do I use this code to replace a section of the code I provided or do I just add it to the existing code?

Comment: put it in your function.php file

Comment: When I add the code to "function.php" file it causes the following error: "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: This is probably because you did not removed the other eventual filter that operates there , forcing an endless loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is the section of code I changed:

```
// The excerpt based on words
function my_string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit)
  array_pop($words);
  return implode(' ', $words).'...';
}
```

I simply replaced the "..." with the following code:

```
<a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">...Read More</a>
```

This is what the final code looked like:

```
// The excerpt based on words
function my_string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit)
  array_pop($words);
  return implode(' ', $words).'<a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">...Read More</a>';
  }
```